# js sequelize chain association accessors

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have three models: Url, Action, Container
I would like to get the Container of a Url through the following relations:

```
db.Url.belongsTo(db.Action, { foreignKey: 'action_id'});
db.Action.belongsTo(db.Container, { foreignKey: 'container_id'});
```

I was hoping for something like:

```
db.Url.findOne(...).getAction().getContainer()
```

However it only seems to work when I work with the entities one after another.

i.e. query the db for the url. Then call url.getAction() and then getContainer.

So it is three separate querys instead of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are asking for a nested include? I don't quite understand what you need to find, the Container through a given Url.id?? Anyaways you're looking for something like this

```
db.Url.find({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.Action,
      include : [{
        model: db.Container
      }]
    }
  ]
})
.then(function(response) {
  return res.json(response);
})
.catch(function (err) {
  // more code...
});
```

This will a return a single json with all corresponding associations.